# GCC Inline-Assembly Error: "Operand size mismatch for 'int'"

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly

first, if somebody knows a function of the Standard C Library, that prints
a string without looking for a binary zero, but requires the number of characters to draw, please tell me!

Otherwise, I have this problem:

```
void printStringWithLength(char *str_ptr, int n_chars){

asm("mov 4, %rax");//Function number (write)
asm("mov 1, %rbx");//File descriptor (stdout)
asm("mov $str_ptr, %rcx");
asm("mov $n_chars, %rdx");
asm("int 0x80");
return;

}
```

GCC tells the following error to the "int" instruction:

```
"Error: operand size mismatch for 'int'"
```

Can somebody tell me the issue?

Comment: You could easily write your own. for loop and putc.

Comment: I know, but this here has other reasons I dont want to speak about :D

Comment: Ooooh, I love a good pointless secret. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817577/what-does-int-0x80-mean-in-assembly-code

Comment: That standard library function is known as **fwrite**.

Comment: That's not how inline assembly works. Things like variable names are not available in inline assembly, if you want to have these things, you need to use [extended inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). Read the article carefully!

Answer (score 10):

There are a number of issues with your code. Let me go over them step by step.

First of all, the `int $0x80` system call interface is for 32 bit code only. [You should not use it in 64 bit code as it only accepts 32 bit arguments.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730/417501) In 64 bit code, use the `syscall` interface. The system calls are similar but some numbers are different.

Second, in AT&T assembly syntax, immediates must be prefixed with a dollar sign. So it's `mov $4, %rax`, not `mov 4, %rax`. The latter would attempt to move the content of address `4` to `rax` which is clearly not what you want.

Third, you can't just refer to the names of automatic variables in inline assembly. You have to tell the compiler what variables you want to use using extended assembly if you need any. For example, in your code, you could do:

```
asm volatile("mov $4, %%eax; mov $1, %%edi; mov %0, %%esi; mov %2, %%edx; syscall"
    :: "r"(str_ptr), "r"(n_chars) : "rdi", "rsi", "rdx", "rax", "memory");
```

Fourth, gcc is an optimizing compiler. By default it assumes that inline assembly statements are like pure functions, that the outputs are a pure function of the explicit inputs.  If the output(s) are unused, the asm statement can be optimized away, or hoisted out of loops if run with the same inputs.

But a system call like `write` has a side-effect you need the compiler to keep, so it's not pure.  You need the asm statement to run the same number of times and in the same order as the C abstract machine would.  [`asm volatile` will make this happen](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile-1).  (An asm statement with no outputs is implicitly volatile, but it's good practice to make it explicit when the side effect is the main purpose of the asm statement.  Plus, we do want to use an output operand to tell the compiler that RAX is modified, as well as being an input, which we couldn't do with a clobber.)

You do always need to accurately describe your asm's inputs, outputs, and clobbers to the compiler using [Extended inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) syntax.  Otherwise you'll step on the compiler's toes (it assumes registers are unchanged unless they're outputs or clobbers).  (Related: [How can I indicate that the memory *pointed* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432259/how-can-i-indicate-that-the-memory-pointed-to-by-an-inline-asm-argument-may-be) shows that a pointer input operand alone does *not* imply that the pointed-to memory is also an input.  Use a dummy `"m"` input or a `"memory"` clobber to force all reachable memory to be in sync.)

You should simplify your code by not writing your own `mov` instructions to put data into registers but rather letting the compiler do this.  For example, your assembly becomes:

```
ssize_t retval;
asm volatile ("syscall"            // note only 1 instruction in the template
    : "=a"(retval)                 // RAX gets the return value
    : "a"(SYS_write), "D"(STDOUT_FILENO), "S"(str_ptr), "d"(n_chars)
    : "memory", "rcx", "r11"       // syscall destroys RCX and R11
  );
```

where `SYS_WRITE` is defined in `<sys/syscall.h>` and `STDOUT_FILENO` in `<stdio.h>`. I am not going to explain all the details of extended inline assembly to you.  Using inline assembly in general is usually a bad idea. Read the documentation if you are interested.  (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info)

Fifth, you should [avoid using inline assembly when you can](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm). For example, to do system calls, use the `syscall` function from `unistd.h`:

```
syscall(SYS_write, STDOUT_FILENO, str_ptr, (size_t)n_chars);
```

This does the right thing.  But it doesn't inline into your code, so use wrapper macros from MUSL for example if you want to really inline a syscall instead of calling a libc function.

Sixth, always check if the system call you want to call is already available in the C standard library. In this case, it is, so you should just write

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, str_ptr, n_chars);
```

and avoid all of this altogether.

Seventh, if you prefer to use `stdio`, use `fwrite` instead:

```
fwrite(str_ptr, 1, n_chars, stdout);
```

Comment: Your use of `"S"(str_ptr)` is actually problematic. This won't guarantee that when inlined and optimized that the contents of that string will actually be dumped to memory first. The potentially expensive and quick fix is to specify the `memory` clobber or better is if you know a particular parameter references memory you can add an extra (unused) memory constraint with something like `"m" (*(const struct {char ch; char str[];} *) ptr_str)` to trick the compiler into ensuring the entire array is dumped to memory before the inline assembly is executed.

Comment: A couple of recent SO questions and answers ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45535396/3857942) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656087/3857942)) spawned interest in this problem that eventually lead to a [GCC mailing post](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2017-08/msg00116.html) on the subject by @DavidWohlferd. One of the questions came from another `syscall` related question where the optimizations caused only some output to be displayed. If anything it shows why inline assembly is dangerous unless you know all the nuances.

Comment: You didn't answer the specific question about why `int 0x80` needs to be `int $0x80` to assemble.  Also, the 3rd arg to functions and syscalls goes in `rdx`.  For `syscall`, the 4th goes in `%r10`, because `syscall` destroys `%rcx` and `%r11` before running any kernel code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: @PeterCordes That applies to you, too.

Comment: You do actually need `asm volatile` here.  The visible side effect of *doing IO* is something you need optimization to preserve!  So you can't let the compiler optimize away the asm statement if the outputs are unused, separate from the `"memory"` clobber.  (Your `asm("syscall" :: ...)` is broken because you didn't tell the compiler that "a" is also written with the return value, and that RCX and R11 are clobbered.  It's implicitly volatile because you have no output operands, but that would change if you used `"+a"` or a separate `"=a"` to make a usable generic wrapper.)

Comment: Your answer still says `asm volatile` is always a bad idea, and seems to imply that `volatile` makes it ok to have un-declared side-effects.  (That's never ok for registers, and only ok for memory if you *also* (not instead) have a `"memory"` clobber).  `asm volatile` is necessary for anything that isn't a pure function of its (declared) input operands.  e.g. on `rdtsc` or system calls other than `getpid` can never be ok without `asm volatile`, so it's not bad in general.  It's only bad when you could have used more specific constraints and avoided it for code that *is* pure.

Comment: @PeterCordes Please do.  It's early in the morning here and I haven't tried to go through the whole thing.

Comment: Ok, it ended up longer than yours, but I think it's accurate now.

Answer (score 4):

There are so many things wrong with your code (and so little reason to use inline asm for it) that it's not worth trying to actually correct all of them.  Instead, [use the `write(2)` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) the normal way, via the POSIX function / libc wrapper as documented in the man page, or use ISO C `<stdio.h>` [`fwrite(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html).

```
#include <unistd.h>

static inline
void printStringWithLength(const char *str_ptr, int n_chars){
    write(1, str_ptr, n_chars);
    // TODO: check error return value
}
```

---

**Why your code doesn't assemble**:

In AT&T syntax, immediates *always* need a `$` decorator.  Your code will assemble if you use `asm("int $0x80")`.

The assembler is complaining about `0x80`, which is a memory reference to the absolute address `0x80`.  There is no [form of `int`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/INT%20n:INTO:INT%203.html) that takes the interrupt vector as anything other than an immediate.  I'm not sure exactly why it complains about the *size*, since memory references don't have an implied size in AT&T syntax.

---

That will get it to assemble, at which point **you'll get linker errors**:

```
In function `printStringWithLength':
5 : <source>:5: undefined reference to `str_ptr'
6 : <source>:6: undefined reference to `n_chars'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[(from the Godbolt compiler explorer)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'void+printStringWithLength(char+*str_ptr,+int+n_chars)%7B%0A%0Aasm(%22mov+4,+%25rax%22)%3B//Function+number+(write)%0Aasm(%22mov+1,+%25rbx%22)%3B//File+descriptor+(stdout)%0Aasm(%22mov+$str_ptr,+%25rcx%22)%3B%0Aasm(%22mov+$n_chars,+%25rdx%22)%3B%0Aasm(%22int+$0x80%22)%3B%0Areturn%3B%0A%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:32.57617223134464,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),header:(),k:34.09049443532203,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.2',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

```
mov $str_ptr, %rcx
```

means to mov-immediate the *address of the symbol `str_ptr`* into `%rcx`.  In AT&T syntax, you don't have to declare external symbols before using them, so unknown names are assumed to be global / static labels.  If you had a global variable called `str_ptr`, that instruction would reference its address (which is a link-time constant, so can be used as an immediate).

---

As other have said, this is *completely* the wrong way to go about things with GNU C inline asm.  See the [inline-assembly](/questions/tagged/inline-assembly) tag wiki for more links to guides.

Also, you're using the wrong ABI.  `int $0x80` is the x86 32-bit system call ABI, so it doesn't work with 64-bit pointers.  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64)

See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.